# Directory permission issue on linux

Tags: linux, centos

I have an NFS Share directory on my linux server.

```
ls: cannot access file: Permission denied
ls: cannot access res: Permission denied
total 20
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ? file
drwx------ 2 root    root    16384 May 19  2015 lost+found
drwxr-x--- 9 lma     lum 4096 Feb 18  2020 lum
d????????? ? ?       ?           ?            ? res
```

When i am trying to change permission as a ***root user*** on the directory file.

```
chmod 775 file
chmod: cannot access `file': Permission denied

chown root:root file
chown: cannot access `file': Permission denied
```

Getting an error, `Permission denied`. Please let me know how can I change permission on the directory

Comment: That looks like a corrupted filesystem to me. Is it a local (internal) disk? External USB disk? Remote NFS or Samba mount?

Comment: It is NFS share directory

Comment: If you list this directory as an ordinary user (not root) do you see it listed properly?

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory holding `file`? `ls -ld dir/`? Can you access the NFS share from the server, what does the directory listing look there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the NFS share is exported with a `no_root_squash` export option, the UID 0 (`root`) of the NFS client host is mapped to UID 65534 (`nobody` or `nfsnobody` in some OSs) on the NFS server. This prevents the root user of the client host from creating evil setuid-root executables on the NFS share and with them illegitimately gaining root access on other NFS clients using the same share, or on the NFS server itself.

The strange question marks may indicate that the `nobody` user has only read access to the directory in question, but no `x` access. This combination means the user can only read the plain `ls` directory listing, but won't be able to access any files within the directory. As a result, any `stat(2)` system calls to get the size/ownership/permission information of those files will also fail.

The fact that only the directories `file` and `res` show question marks while `lost+found` and `lum` are displayed normally may be caused by the group memberships held by the root user of the client host, the use of ACLs or SELinux on the server system, or a combination of these factors.

If this is the problem, you cannot fix it over NFS. You will need to log into the NFS server system, and access the filesystem locally there.

You should ideally design the group assignments of your NFS share directories so that nothing within the share is owned by the NFS server's `root` user (unless it should be explicitly read-only or inaccessible for all clients).

If you must have the `root` ownership preserved across the client/server connection, you can do it by adding the export option `no_root_squash` to the share's definition in the `/etc/exports` file on the NFS server, and re-exporting the share. But if you do that, you should either have the filesystem that contains the share on the NFS server be mounted with the `noexec,nosuid` mount options.

Comment: the funny thing is that the permission to `stat()` the files should be the same for all files, namely the `x` bit on the directory, like you said. ACLs shouldn't be able to affect that on a per-file basis. SELinux maybe could.